# php CRYPT_BLOWFISH in as3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, air, cryptography, blowfish

In php you can use [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function and give it a salt beginning with "$2a$" to crypt the string using CRYPT_BLOWFISH.

For example.

```
echo crypt("test", "$2a$13$1mFan0ihXzWfxATGXSKRqe");
//output: $2a$13$1mFan0ihXzWfxATGXSKRqedMoYWoXpPizu4Q274LnpVVJ7gyza3Lq
```

I tried to generate the output in as3 using the [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) library. The code snippet I tried.

```
var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray("$2a$13$1mFan0ihXzWfxATGXSKRqe");
var blowfish:BlowFishKey = new BlowFishKey(key);
var dataBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
dataBytes.writeUTFBytes("test");
blowfish.encrypt(dataBytes);
var encrypted:String = Hex.fromArray(dataBytes).toUpperCase();
trace(encrypted);
//output: 986C8D386BEAD6AE
```

I don't think those blowfish ciphers are the same. The php blowfish based on bcrypt is one way  according to the documentation on php.net. In as3 I can also decrypt the encrypted message.

I searched for blowfish library that in as3 that gives the same output as in php without succes. Anyone knows how to generate the same output in actionscript 3.0 as in php?

**UPDATE**

I am using adobe air. So a native solution is also acceptable. I could create a native extension or use a NativeProcess to acces it to do the encryption instead of as3.

**UPDATE 2**
For now I am using a command line program created with c# using bcrypt class found on http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx

Comment: Try to see if the contents of this post can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622011/cant-create-as3-compatible-blowfish-string-in-ruby

Comment: In that post is also mentioned that the as3 version is using a different method than server side blowfish encryptions :(